# Why does the C++ output does not reach the socket until after I press enter?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am trying to implement a shell emulator as part of an assignment which has to use sockets as the transmission medium. The issue I currently face is that upon the calling of the list command to list active processes (invoked on server), the client side doesn't receive data until after I press the Enter key. Attaching the relevant snippets of code:

**server.cpp**

```
else if(strcmp(token, "list") == 0) {
                    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    if (token == NULL) { //Active Processes
                        //char headerBuffer[256];
                        //int n = sprintf(headerBuffer, "%d", i);
                        //write(STDOUT_FILENO, headerBuffer, n);
                        //write(msgsock, headerBuffer, n);
                        char output[4096];
                        char temp[256];

                        for(int it = 0; it < i; it++) {
                            if (processes[it].status == 1) {
                                processes[it].elapsedTime = difftime(time(0), processes[it].startTime);
                                sprintf(temp, "Process Name: %s\n", processes[it].processName);
                                strcat(output, temp);
                                bzero(temp, sizeof(temp));

                                sprintf(temp, "Process ID: %d\n", processes[it].processID);
                                strcat(output, temp);
                                bzero(temp, sizeof(temp));

                                sprintf(temp, "Process Status [0 - Closed, 1 - Running]: %d\n", processes[it].status);
                                strcat(output, temp);
                                bzero(temp, sizeof(temp));  

                                sprintf(temp, "Starting Time: %s", ctime(&processes[it].startTime));
                                strcat(output, temp);
                                bzero(temp, sizeof(temp));

                                sprintf(temp, "Elapsed Time: %ds\n", (int) processes[it].elapsedTime);
                                strcat(output, temp);
                                bzero(temp, sizeof(temp));
                            }
                        }
                        if (write(msgsock, output, strlen(output)) == -1) {
                            perror("write to socket");
                        }
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, output, strlen(output));
                        bzero(output, sizeof(output));
```

**client.cpp**

```
while (true) {
    int bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1024);
    write(sock_child, buf, bytes_read);

    int to_write = read(sock_child, output, 4096);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, output, to_write);
    bzero(output, sizeof(output));
    //write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what the problem is, how can you be sure what's relevant? In this case the limiting factor is likely how you are taking user data in the first place. All of the standard C and C++ input routines don't move user input from the buffer to whatever you use to read the input until you hit enter.

Comment: I have implemented other functionalities like add/subtract numbers that go from the client side to the server side which then returns the results to client. I didn't need to press enter for that output to appear, the output returned as soon as I gave the command and pressed enter.

Comment: Your client is only ever waiting for one of the two sides to send it data. How does it know which one is the right one to wait for?